# Installing mysql-server on 10.04LTS gives "404 Not Found" error

Tags: installation, apt, mysql

Hi I am trying to install mysql on Ubuntu 10.04LTS (Lucid Lynx) and I am getting this error.  Is this a server side issue - is the server up?  I am running this from the command line on a remote server...

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libhtml-template-perl libmysqlclient16 libnet-daemon-perl libplrpc-perl mysql-client-5.1
  mysql-client-core-5.1 mysql-common mysql-server-5.1 mysql-server-core-5.1 psmisc
Suggested packages:
  dbishell libipc-sharedcache-perl tinyca mailx
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libhtml-template-perl libmysqlclient16 libnet-daemon-perl libplrpc-perl mysql-client-5.1
  mysql-client-core-5.1 mysql-common mysql-server mysql-server-5.1 mysql-server-core-5.1 psmisc
0 upgraded, 13 newly installed, 0 to remove and 85 not upgraded.
Need to get 23.2MB/24.3MB of archives.
After this operation, 61.7MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main mysql-common 5.1.62-0ubuntu0.10.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.192 80]

<more of the same error messages here> 

Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-dfsg-5.1/mysql-common_5.1.62-0ubuntu0.10.04.1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.166 80]

<more of the same error messages here>

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to run `sudo apt-get update` first and then try again; that specific version is obsolete and [has been updated](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-dfsg-5.1/)